# Replace wildcard signing certificate and provisioning profile for app in App Store

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, app-store, provisioning-profile, code-signing-entitlements

I am working on an app to which we need to add Push Notifications. However, it turns out that when the app was released to the App Store it was done so with a generic (wildcard) certificate and provisioning profile. Since we cannot add the Push Notifications entitlement to a wildcard provisioning profile we need to create a new one using a specific app id. However, if I understand it correctly, this would prevent us from simply updating the existing App Store app, possibly forcing us to release a separate replacement app, losing all our users.

Is there a solution to this problem? I am thinking that other people must have encountered the issue before us.

Comment: Is your app live ?

Comment: Yes, it has been alive for a few months.

Comment: You can update the version +1 then.It will be new instance of the same app and will prevent the lose of your users

Comment: As far as I know, you can't push a build to the app store with a wildcard distribution provisioning profile.   Are you sure it was built that way?  Using a new certificate shouldn't be an issue, and the bundle ID in the provisioning profile is not what decided whether an app is a new app vs. an update to an existing app.  That is controlled by the bundle ID of the app itself.  As long as the app's bundle ID hasn't changed, it will be treated as a new version in iTunes Connect.

Comment: @wottle You can certainly release to App Store with a wildcard provisioning profile, but you cannot add entitlements to it, which is exactly our issue here.
Using a new certificate *does* have some issues, like losing access to the data stored in the keychain. This is a price we are willing to pay, as long as it actually let as do an update.